# fluent-ffmpeg error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: At least one output file must be specified

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a simple video from several images on node js.

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg().input('input.txt')
.inputOption(["-f concat"])
.outputOptions("-c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p")
.output('output.mp4')
.on('start', (commandLine) => {
console.log(`FFmpeg command: ${commandLine}`);
})
.on('end', () => {
console.log('completed');
}).on('error', (err) => {
console.error('error occurred: ' + err.message);
}).run();
```

and input.txt is

```
file 'test1.png'
duration 2
file 'test2.png'
duration 30
file 'test3.png'
duration 4
```

I don't know why but this code doesn't work. but if i copy and paste the code from ${commandLine}, it works!!??

```
PS C:\\Users\\donghwan\\Documents\\GitHub\\create_video\\src\> node test.js
FFmpeg command: ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -y -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
error occurred: ffmpeg exited with code 1: At least one output file must be specified

PS C:\\Users\\donghwan\\Documents\\GitHub\\create_video\\src\> ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -y -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2023-08-20-git-f0b1cab538-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers

and so on...
```

I'm so confused and i tried to find any other reason for this but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe it's `save` instead of `output`. Output seems to serve for other purposes, at least I don't see its usage in their examples (check the repo and examples folder).

Comment: On the other side, it's probably because of outputOptions format. I'd say it's an array of arguments, not a string, according to their docs. Follow their format :)

Comment: you're right it worked!!